# Does Sonarqube support SQL 2016?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Does SonarQube support SQL 2016?

Based on documentation ([Link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements)), I did not find any useful information.

Comment: SQL:2016 is a SQL standard that is not yet even published. Why do you expect any tool to support that before it is released?

Comment: This is now available in SonarQube 6.6+, snice Oct. 2017

Answer (score 4):

Not yet (May 2017)

This is requested and followed by [`SONAR-8632`](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8632): "Support Microsoft SQL Server 2016".
You can watch and vote this issue up.

Update January 2018:

This is closed and available in [SonarQube 6.6](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR/fixforversion/13961/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel) (Oct. 2017).

Comment: This is supported now in version 6.6+